# Cannot access data in array, name[0] is undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to get access to data from my array that I got from calling `fetch`.

When I print the data e.g. `console.log(data)`, I get the result I want. However, when I attempt to print the first item e.g. `console.log(data[0])`, I see `undefined`.

```js
componentDidMount = () => {
  fetch("http://localhost/system_reklamacji/php/pobierz_pliki.php", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      'klucz_nr': this.state.id,

    })
  }).then(res => this.KonkretnePliki(res.json()));
```

And the function where the error occurs:

```js
KonkretnePliki(e) {
  let pliki = [];

  (e.then(function(value) {
    value.forEach(element => {
      console.log(element[0]);
      let temp = {
        'nazwa': element[0],
        'sciezka': element[1],
        'typ': element[1].slice(element[1].length - 3, ),
      };
      console.log(pliki[0]); // **shows all the information i want**
      pliki.push(temp);
    })
  }));

  console.log(pliki[0]); // **shows undefined**
  this.setState({
    dane: pliki
  });
}
```

Is there any way for me to get the desired data outside of `forEach` loop?

Comment: may be your 'data' is an object not an array.

Comment: can you post data output what is ?

Comment: Checked that with isArray function

Comment: Then if it is "array like" wrap data with... `Array.from(data)`

Comment: `e.then` creates a promise again, so I’d say you have a run of the mill async issue here …

Comment: @MariuszRakoczy So does isArray fucntion returned true?

Comment: @04FS when removing the e.then i just get `e.forEach is not a function`

Comment: Who said you should remove it … You simply mustn’t try to access data that gets created in an async process, outside of that async process. Put `this.setState({dane:pliki});` _after_ the foreach, but _inside_ the `e.then` callback function ... that should be all that’s needed here, no?

Comment: @04FS then i get error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

Comment: Okay, that should be due to `this` pointing towards something different inside the promise then. Store the “outer” this into a helper variable before then, `var that = this;`, and then inside the callback use `that.setState`.

Comment: Or just use arrow function instead of "function(value)". (value) => {....}